# Web Layer Unit Test and Integration Test in Spring 5.0.7.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mocking, mockito

I have a SpringBoot app. with this test, but it does not inject and mock the classes

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
        "classpath:testDatabaseContext.xml",
        "classpath:testServicesContext.xml",
        "classpath:servlet.xml"
})
public class TerritoriClandestiControllerTest  {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    TerritoriClandestiRepository territoriClandestiRepository = mock(TerritoriClandestiRepository.class);

    @InjectMocks
    private TerritoriClandestiService territoriClandestiService;

    List<Object[]> list;

    Resource listResource = new ClassPathResource("list.txt");

    @Before
    public void setup() throws IOException {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac)
                .build();
        list = DataLoader.readLines(listgetInputStream());
    }

    @Test
    public void getAll() throws Exception {

        when(territoriClandestiRepository.findAllBaseData(anyLong())).thenReturn(list);

        mockMvc.perform(get("/terrcland")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.*", hasSize(1)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@MockBean` instead of `@Mock`, it will export the field as a bean in the spring context.

```java
public class TerritoriClandestiControllerTest  {
   @MockBean
   private TerritoriClandestiRepository territoriClandestiRepository;
}
```

Alternatively you can also do something like this

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
        "classpath:testDatabaseContext.xml",
        "classpath:testServicesContext.xml",
        "classpath:servlet.xml"
}, classes = {TerritoriClandestiControllerTest.Config.class})
public class TerritoriClandestiControllerTest  {
   
   @TestConfiguration
   static class Config {
      @Bean
      TerritoriClandestiRepository territoriClandestiRepository() {
         return Mockito.mock(TerritoriClandestiRepository.class);
      }
   }

   @Autowired
   private TerritoriClandestiRepository territoriClandestiRepository;
}
```